# regex: I want to check whether any english dictionary words are present in my text file

Tags: regex

I have text file with more sanskrit words. But inbetween there are some english sentences by mistake. Its very big file and difficult to scroll and check. So is there a way using regex i can find any matching english dictionary words in that file

```
duñkaraà me babhüvätra
     tvädåçaà mäna-bhaïjanam
ato 'tra muralé tyaktä
     lajjayaiva mayä priyä
aho bata mayä tatra
     kåtaà yädåk sthitaà yathä
tad astu kila düre 'tra
     nirvaktuà ca na çakyate
     The situation there cannot even be described here.
ekaù sa me tad vraja-loka-vat priyas
     tädåë mahä-prema-bhara-prabhävataù
vakñyaty adaù kiïcana bädaräyanir
     maj-jévite çiñya-vare sva-sannibhe
çré-parékñid uväca 
etädåçaà tad vraja-bhägya-vaibhavaà
     samrambhataù kértayato mahä-prabhoù
punas tathä bhäva-niveça-çaìkayä
```

In the above tex i `The situation there cannot even be described here.` So is there any easy way to search out whether there are any english dictionary words.

I am using linux. So any command is fine. But prefer using regex.

Answer (score 0):

If each 'Sanskrit' word always has a special character like 'ù', then you could check against a regex of a word `(\w+)`.

Since this is not the case for words like 'priyas', you would have to check each word in a data store that holds all the English words. Unfortunately, you cannot check for a valid English word any other way.

A faster search could be done using a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: Nice catch!! If English words only appear in their own dedicated lines this can be done by checking for any non-english words in that line. Slightly more code then.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the Unicode of Linux. But I can provide you some directions.

1. According to [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_(Unicode_block)), Sanskrit characters belongs to Devanagari Unicode block.
2. Devanagari Unicode block is on `A8E0— A8FF`. You can find [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/#devanagari-extended-characters).

   You may need tools to convert to UTF8 such as [this tool](https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter).
3. Set up the Regex condition excluding Devanagari Unicode block.

   ```
    \S+[^\s\xA8E0-\xA8FF.]+.*
   ```

### Regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JdINDq/1)

This will be easier to find English sentences.

Comment: Another easy tool is Google translate. You will find a sentence that is translated into other languages such as Chinese.